# How do you load a simpletransformers model from a checkpoint?

Tags: python, model, loading, simpletransformers

I'm using simpletransformers (https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers) for a work project. After training a model, I get a bunch of files dumped to the output folder. I was wondering, if you wanted to load in a previously trained model (which I assume is saved to the output folder) so that you can immediately run it against new data, how would one go about doing this?[Picture of files in output folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Rnw.png)

With scikit-learn, you can export models to json easily, and load them back in, I figured there might be a similar process for this?

Answer (score 5):

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

model = ClassificationModel("bert", "outputs/best_model")
model.predict(['Enter text to classify'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
model = ClassificationModel(model_name, model_path, num_labels=no_labels)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.